# Latest Linux doesn't boot after shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, linux-kernel, acpi, hp

I'm fairly new to desktop Linux. I have a bit of experience using Debian on a server.

I have an HP Pavilion 15-n072sr laptop, which I tried to make a little bit more useful by installing Linux on it, as it somewhat struggles with the latest Windows 10 version. This laptop is running **the latest version of BIOS** - Insyde F.72

### Ubuntu

My first pick was Ubuntu. I decided to download the latest 23.10 version, not 22.04 LTS, as I  want to try the newest features and the newest versions of Gnome.

The OS did install, but when I **power off** my laptop and then turn it on, the screen immediately gets spammed with the error message

```
ACPI Error: No handler or method for GPE XX, disabling event (20230331/evgpe-839)
```

And some other message that I cannot read, as it is overlayed by the abovementioned one. I don't even see the HP and Ubuntu logos on startup.

The problem occurs only when I **Shutdown** the laptop. If I have Ubuntu running and press **Restart** the OS starts perfectly. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu 23.10, but still get the same problem.

I decided to try installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and it worked flawlessly. Then I decided to update it to Ubuntu 23.04 by disabling updating only to LTS in the update manager, and then to Ubuntu 23.10. The problem was still present.

### Manjaro

I also tried installing Manjaro, but the installer just won't start when I choose the option to boot either with proprietary drivers or open-source ones

### Fedora

Next, I tried Fedora Workstation 38. The OS installed perfectly and worked flawlessly, it even booted up after I **power off** the laptop. It immediately asked for updates (including the system update) in the App Centre.

When the updates were downloaded, I pressed "Restart & Install". After the updates were installed (there was a long wait with an update screen), the system booted up perfectly, but when I tried to **power off** the laptop and boot it up again the system wouldn't load at all:

1. The system would show a black screen with a static white text cursor unresponsive to any key presses and would be stuck there
2. Sometimes the booting will go a little further and would be stuck at the HP & Fedora loading screen. When I click ESC to see what was happening, I see the repeated message

```
[FAILED] Failed to start systemd-journald.service - Journal Service
See 'systemcl status systemd-journald.service' for details
Starting start systemd-journald.service - Journal Service...
```

When I physically power off the laptop by holding the power button, and then turn it on, I see Grub with these options:

1. `Fedora Linux (6.5.9-200.fc38.x86_64) 38 (Workstation Edition)`
2. `Fedora Linux (6.2.9-300.fc38.x86_64) 38 (Workstation Edition)`
3. `Fedora Linux (0-rescue-[UUID]) 38 (Workstation Edition)`
4. `UEFI Firmware Settings`

I've noticed that the problem occurs only with the kernel version 6.5.9-200, with all the other options like 6.2.9-300 or rescue mode the OS boots perfectly fine.

I had to temporarily default to kernel versions 6.2.9-300 for the laptop to be of any use. But I really want to use the latest kernel, so this question on StackExchange is my last hope.

I tried installing the Fedora Workstation 39 beta, but the installation wouldn't even boot, with the same problem I faced when trying to boot `Fedora Linux (6.5.9-200.fc38.x86_64) 38 (Workstation Edition)`

### Things I tried

`pci=nommconf` does nothing

`acpi=off` does solve the problem but it makes Gnome super laggy, disables all the animations and makes it use X11

I have two ram sticks in my laptop: a 4GB one, and an 8GB one. As I read on Fedora forums, I tried removing one of them, but it did not help.

Trying to reinstall the OS does not seem to help, but installing a previous version like Ubuntu 22.04 LTS or not updating Fedora 38 via App Centre eliminates the problem. I really want to use the latest version, though.

Comment: Did you try Debian? Debian 12 will stick to its kernel `6.1.0` for the foreseeable future. You can get recent software versions from the [backports](https://backports.debian.org/) repository and flatpaks.

Comment: @td211, I've tried installing Debian 12 just now, and it works perfectly fine! However, I'd still like to understand the root of the problem I'm facing with the newer kernel. I'd really like to get Ubuntu or Fedora running on this laptop

Comment: You could dual boot with Fedora to try collect more logs and report the issue to kernel maintainers. You should use the latest mainline kernel for kernel bug reports. Side note: Ubuntu is basically Debian with canonical modifications, you can tune Debian to your liking.

Comment: @td211, I'm not sure what tools to use to collect boot logs, and I'm not sure whether my issue is specifically with a newer kernel or with something else.
I know that Ubuntu is Debian-based, and I had prior experience working on Debian. But the thing I want is the latest version of Gnome, to be honest. I know there are Debian Testing and Debian Experimental, but I've heard they are way less stable than the latest release of Ubuntu or Fedora. In short, as I heard, Ubuntu or Fedora provide more up-to-date software

Comment: For the best GNOME experience, you better go with Fedora then. You can roll with Debian unstable, it shouldn't break ofter (it is unstable as in packages update often, not as in beta software).

Comment: @td211, thanks for the advice! The thing is that I can't run the latest version of Fedora. xD. I use Debian 12 for now, but I really want to fix my problem

Comment: From what I've read on forums the issue might be with BIOS, but I'm running the latest version of it. So maybe this laptop is just incompatible with the latest kernel, which is very sad

Comment: You mean the firmware or the BIOS boot mode? I assume you must be using UEFI. I expect a new laptop to be incompatible with older kernels not the other way around. As for Debian, if you want you can run the unstable branch, which is like a rolling release so it should get the latest GNOME even before Fedora. (Don't let the name deceive you, Debian unstable is not unusable, it is unstable in the sense of changing package versions).

Comment: Yes, I use UEFI, but even when I boot with Legacy mode the problem is still present. From what I understand, my 2013 laptop can't run kernel 6.5 (Fedora 38 on kernel 6.2.9 works perfectly, but it doesn't work on kernel 6.5.9).

Comment: Maybe it's a hardware issue, I honestly don't know anymore. Tomorrow I'm going to show it to a person who has a lot of experience fixing computers, maybe they will find the root of the problem.

Comment: I don't think it is a hardware issue. You should talk to kernel maintainers.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure which tools to use to collect the necessary logs. I used ```journalctl``` previously, but that's probably not enough. I'm not sure where should I submit my question. I shouldn't submit it as a bug right away, not until I'm at least 90% certain that it's the kernel's fault

Comment: `journalctl -k -b -1` shows the kernel logs of the last boot. The fact that disabling ACPI fixes the issue indicates that it is an ACPI bug, so likely the kernel or a buggy firmware.

Comment: I haven't replied in a while, sorry! I've found that there are no logs for an unsuccessful boot with Fedora 38 on kernel 6.5.9. After an unsuccessful boot, I start a kernel 6.2.9 session and use `journalctl `, but there are just no logs for the previous boot attempt. I guess that's because the boot fails with `[FAILED] Failed to start systemd-journald.service - Journal Service` with kernel 6.5.9

Comment: Add a password to the root account and try to boot to an `initramfs` rescue shell. From there check the logs.